# getting error 405 'Method not Allowed' When trying to send request to my node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Its my first time using Express and MongoDB, i have created my Node server and connected it to my mongoDB database, but when i try to send an request from my html page to the server i get Error 405 method not allowed, following is my node.js server code

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userdatabase' ,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
const app = express()
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const port = 5500

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is up at ${port}`)
})
   
app.post('/api/register', async(req, res) => {
const {username, password} = req.body
res.json({status: 'ok'})
try{
    const response = await User.create({
        username,
        password
    })
    console.log('User created succesfully' , response)
}catch(error){
    console.log(error)
}
})
```

and here is the function im trying to call to do the post request

```js
  const form = document.querySelector('#register')
form.addEventListener('submit', registerUser)

async function registerUser(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value

const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }, body: JSON.stringify({
      username,
      password
    })
  }).then(res => res.json())
}
```

basically i am creating an login system and try to register users, but for some reason i keep getting the error 405 when trying to call the Server, Note that for some reason it worked 3 times when i was trying earlier, I havent changed almost anything in the code but it just wont work, what it can be ? thanks in advance

Comment: I think the route '/api/register' does not have any method 
, and in your code not defined that method or file ,
this line `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))` not wrong should  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))` 




my question is where is `/api/register` declaration

Comment: @bhavesh probably is that i will do some better research on how to do it right, thanks, as its my first time trying to create an server and connect to an database i dont know exactly how to do it, basically i need to declare the ```/api/register``` endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell in which port mongoDB would run.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it that isn't the issue, when the port is the default one (27017) you dont need to declare it

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to declare the server and port while calling the axios. The axios call should be - `await fetch('localhost:5500/api/register')`. It's searching for '/api/register' but didn't find anything. Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Issue solved : the html file wasn't in the folder 'static'  probably i have moved it and didn't noticed, sorry for the question guys, if anyone have the same problem make sure to check it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).